# What's the alternative for VMSupport?

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, jvm-hotspot

int java8 the `sun.misc.VMSupport` util provides multi apis like `getAgentProperties()` etc. However, this util is removed in java11 release. Is there any alternative for this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java 11+ alternative is the `com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine` class ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.attach/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html)) which provides a `getAgentProperties()` method.

From the javadoc:

> The following example demonstrates how `VirtualMachine` may be used:

```
  // attach to target VM
  VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach("2177");

  // start management agent
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port", "5000");
  vm.startManagementAgent(props);

  // detach
  vm.detach();
```

You can also get a `VirtualMachine` object from the `AttachProvider` API ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.attach/com/sun/tools/attach/spi/AttachProvider.html)).

<sup>(Note that the `VMSupport` class is still in the Java 17 code base as `jdk.internal.vm.VMSupport`, but Java 17 will stop you using it unless you apply a very big sledgehammer.  Just don't.)</sup>

Comment: How to access VirtualMachine instance in java agent? I can only access `Instrumentation` instance

Comment: Big sledgehammer: `--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED` as argument to javac and java.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn – To me, that is a big sledgehammer …

Comment: @JohannesKuhn what's the use of this argument?

Comment: Allow you to use `jdk.internal.vm.VMSupport`. But it's a bad idea, as you tie your code to a specific java implementation.

Comment: @scottxiao why do you need access to these properties which are clearly for the JMX agent and not your agent?